# Is there a test case available (simulator) for search engine bots

Tags: php, proxy, simulator, bots, testcase

I have wrote myself a very strong protection class "BlockIp" that can use a blacklist with ip's and can detect strange IP configuration's and can block proxies. When it found one, i get a detailed email about the visitor and why it is blocked and what they want to try to do (once a day of course). It seems that it is working very well because i received some real attacks in the past that have been blocked by this class. It does not block legal bots, but that is not easy to test that the detection method is correct.

Today i get an email from the class that it has blocked "ycar10.mobile.bf1.yahoo.com", it identifies itself as a yahoo robot but was behind a proxy. I search the net if it was blacklisted but didn't found that it is blacklisted. So the question is: Is it right to block bots behind a proxy (use legal bots proxy's anyway?)? Here some information about the bot:

```
HTTP_ACCEPT = */*
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR = 107.38.3.137,  98.137.88.60
HTTP_USER_AGENT = YahooCacheSystem
PATH = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE = 
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.2.14
SERVER_PORT = 80
REMOTE_ADDR = 98.139.241.249
REMOTE_PORT = 53863
GATEWAY_INTERFACE = CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL = HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD = GET
QUERY_STRING = 
REQUEST_URI = /
SCRIPT_NAME = /index.php
PHP_SELF = /index.php
REQUEST_TIME = 1330923844
```

Otherwise, is there a test case (suite/simulator) to be able to the test the correct behaviour of a legal bot (only allowing the major ones such as: Google, Yahoo, Bing), to be sure i used the right detection method. There are some simulators around, but most of them are not working properly and the next question is: "can i trust it...".

*Notice: As you can see in the details above, it is using a REMOTE_PORT value of 53863, what kind of port is 53863?*

I hope you can understand my question, if not, drop a line here.

Comment: Remote ports can be anything the client chooses.  Bots can use proxies if they feel like it.  Fake bots can use any User-Agent they feel like.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know bots can use proxies, but does the legal ones (such as Google, Yahoo and Bing) use sometimes proxies? Otherwise the detection method is right, right?

Comment: How are you defining a "legal" proxy?  Do you only care about Google, Yahoo, and Bing, or do you care about all of them?  My point is that you cannot be certain in any case about the requests you are receiving.  All of the information can be spoofed.

Comment: Yes i do only care about the legal search engines (Google, Yahoo and Bing). Do they use proxies anyway, otherwise i can block them if it is a proxy when a proxy identify itself as legal search engine.

Comment: http://www.affiliatebeginnersguide.com/articles/block_bots.html
This article may be helpful, did the above bot make a request to robots.txt before attempting index? If not then it may very well be a user-agent spoof

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info. It did not a request for robots.txt. By analyzing the IP's with IPNetInfo i think it was correctly to block this one. 2 of the 3 IP's are from Yahoo, and one from Sprint Nexttel Corporation. I already found that it is possible to setup a proxy search engine to hide original location of spoofer. But, use yahoo and other search engines proxies by themselves? If not i think it is a good thing to block all proxies that identifies itself as a legal search engine.

Comment: Hm... Isn't there a way to hide yourself and don't let other people know you're using a proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Port number 53863 is a valid port, not being reserved for anything. The computer that connects to your server can chose any port for that particular connection (although you'll probably see port numbers above 1024).

You can use sites like web-sniffer.net that can identify themselves as GoogleBot. The downside is that they only spoof the user-agent, not the behavior (I doubt they are checking for robots.txt first).

As a personal advice, please do not try to block many IPs at once and check online blacklists. If you start blocking a lot of IPs you may end up realizing that you've blocked trusted bots and you'll have no way to know which ones they were.